What category of grammar does word choice (diction) come under?
I am trying to organise my notes about grammar into categories. I was hoping someone would be able to tell me which category Diction (word choice) comes under, if any — morphology or syntax? I wonder if I should rename "syntax" category into "syntax and diction". Any thoughts? thanks


It seems to be a category of its own: OED -- diction -- 3.a.
The manner in which anything is expressed in (spoken or written) words; choice or selection of words and phrases; wording, phrasing; verbal style.

The criterion one chooses words can be so various... It can concern semantics (looking for synonyms for example), register (wanting to evoke a certain social class or indicate whether it is formal or informal speech), style (lyric, academic etc.), that it is indeed difficult to classify it.

Maybe if you explain what you mean by word choice/diction.

@StuartF Choosing what word to use (in a phrase or sentence)

As I hoped to find, Oxford online shows that diction is (1) word choice in speech and writing, and (2) pronunciation As I hear it, good diction is clear pronunciation and nothing more.

Surely the 'choice of word' sense of diction falls  very largely under [the lexical branch of] semantics, though style choice is also involved. But grammar, pragmatics and semantics are usually treated as distinct (though there are necessarily overlaps when analysing strings).

Stress, Pronunciation, Intonation and Diction, for example. You need a speech/written language category.

@Yosef Baskin I'd say that the 'enunciation' sense is default, but ODE, courtesy of Google lists the '[1] the choice and use of words and phrases in speech or writing.
"Wordsworth campaigned against exaggerated poetic diction" ' (phraseology) sense first.

word choice is usually not diction.

@Lambie It doesn't matter what it usually means, it matters what it means in the sense and context that the OP is concerned about.
